# DataFrame Merge Produces More Rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two CSV files and I want to use two DataFrames to perform a lookup of values in the first table. Here are the sample table formats (with sample data in them).  I want to take each email field in the **DF_SPO** below and lookup the user value in the **DF_REF** dataframe to add two new columns to the table.

```
DF_SPO
+--------+-------------------+--------------------------+
| tbl_id |      EMAIL1       |          EMAIL2          |
+--------+-------------------+--------------------------+
|      1 | test@example.com  | anotheruser@example.com  |
|      2 | test2@example.com | anotheruser2@example.com |
+--------+-------------------+--------------------------+

DF_HRI
+--------------------------+---------------+
|          email           |   user        |
+--------------------------+---------------+
| test@example.com         | test_user     |
| test2@example.com        | test_user_2   |
| anotheruser@example.com  | another_user  |
| anotheruser2@example.com | another_user2 |
+--------------------------+---------------+


DF_SPO_MERGED
+--------+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------+-----------------+
| tbl_id |       EMAIL1      |           EMAIL2         | primaryUser  |  secondaryUser  |
+--------+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------+-----------------+
|      1 | test@example.com  | anotheruser@example.com  | test_user    | another_user    |
|      2 | test2@example.com | anotheruser2@example.com | test_user_2  | another_user_2  |
+--------+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

Based on this diagram, here is the code that I am using to perform the lookups of each email address.

```
import pandas as pd

df_spo = pd.read_csv("InventoryFeeds-SPO.csv", encoding="utf-8")
df_ref = pd.read_csv("InventoryFeeds-REF.csv", encoding="utf-8", dtype = {'user_num': str})

# Filter Reference Feed to contain only Email & Username
df_ref = df_ref.filter(['email', 'user'])
df_ref.drop_duplicates(subset='email', keep="last")


print(f"DF REF Size - {df_ref.size} | DF REF Shape - {df_ref.shape}")
print(f"DF SPO Size - {df_spo.size} | DF SPO Shape - {df_spo.shape}")

print("=" * 60)

print("MERGING Primary Owner!")
df_spo = df_spo.merge(df_ref, left_on='EMAIL1', right_on="email", how="left")
df_spo.rename(columns={"user": "primaryUser"}, inplace=True)
df_spo.drop('email', axis=1, inplace=True)
print(f"NEW DF SPO Size - {df_spo.size} | NEW DF SPO Shape - {df_spo.shape}")
```

The first merge works, but I end up with way more rows than I expected.

```
DF HRI Size - 203234 | DF HRI Shape - (101617, 2)
DF SPO Size - 23268 | DF SPO Shape - (1939, 12)
============================================================
MERGING Primary Owner!
NEW DF SPO Size - 3336326 | NEW DF SPO Shape - (238309, 14)
```

Is there something I am missing? Trying to figure out why I get so many extra rows in my resulting merged dataframe.

Thanks!

Comment: You did not actually drop the duplicate values. You need to assign the `drop_duplicates` line to a variable or use the `inplace` param: `df_ref = df_ref.drop_duplicates(subset='email', keep="last")` or `df_ref.drop_duplicates(subset='email', keep="last", inplace=True)`

Comment: @It_is_Chris thank you - this was exactly it. Strange that a few duplicates caused such a discrepancy in data. If you want to post this as an answer I can mark it as the Solution since it is correct.